# Floating rock found in southern florida

Tags: ocean

I found the rock on the beach.  It has a redish hue and floats on water.  It feels as though it is hollow because it is light for its size.  Does anyone have an idea what this is?[image]

Comment: you sure its not plastic?

Comment: Rocks usually do not float on water. The only rocks that float on water are very porous rocks like [pumice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumice).

Answer (score 10):

This isn't a rock at all, but a seed of *[Entada Gigas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entada_gigas)*, sometimes called the **sea heart** or **sea bean**.

[image: Entada Gigas seeds]
([CC-BY-SA-3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Entada_gigas1.jpg#mw-jump-to-license))

*Entada Gigas* is called the "sea bean" for good reason: it's a member of the bean family *[Fabaceae](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae)*. In fact, this species has the family's largest seed,  a flattened heart shape 6 cm in diameter and 2 cm thick.  These hollow seeds are washed into the ocean and drift on currents for up to 2 years, on the chance that one will wash up somewhere to germinate.  It seems that sea beans have evolved to propagate in this way, similar to [coconut](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coconut)s.